# What is the Difference between Android, Windows mobile and Apple iOS?

Tags: android

Hi I want to know what is the exact difference between Android, Windows mobile and Apple iOS and what art their limitation

Comment: That's a very broad question.

Comment: In what respect? Could you clarify your question a little more please?

Comment: Beyond Compare is a good tool for running differences.

Comment: In terms of development or deployment, or both?

Answer (score 3):

Android applications are written in Java and can be developed in any operating system. iOS applications are written in Objective-C and must be written on an Apple Mac computer. Windows mobile applications are written in C#, C++ or VB; I would guess you need to develop in Windows, but don't know.

You do need to be more specific though for your question to be answered properly.

Answer (score 0):

They are different operating systems. That answers one of the two questions.